# Calculate rotated rectangle coordinates with top left transform origin

Tags: javascript, rotation, 2d, computational-geometry

I'm trying to draw the 4 cornes of this rotated rectangle with a top left transform origin. Right now, the red rectangle is drawn exactly like I want but I'm trying to draw the fours cornes but as you can see it looks like the coordinates are shifted but I don't understand why. How can I correct the green corner coordinates so they match the red rectangle.

The x and y coordinates of the red rectangle corresponds to the rotated top left corner of the rectangle

```js
function radians(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function getPointRotated(X, Y, R, Xos, Yos) {
  var rotatedX = X + Xos * Math.cos(radians(R)) - Yos * Math.sin(radians(R));
  var rotatedY = Y + Xos * Math.sin(radians(R)) + Yos * Math.cos(radians(R));

  return {
    x: rotatedX,
    y: rotatedY
  };
}

const rect = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 150,
  height: 50,
  rotation: 45
};

const htmlRect = document.createElement("div");
htmlRect.style.height = rect.height + "px";
htmlRect.style.width = rect.width + "px";
htmlRect.style.position = "absolute";
htmlRect.style.background = "red";
htmlRect.style.transformOrigin = "top left";
htmlRect.style.transform = `translate3d(${rect.x}px,${rect.y}px,0) rotate(${rect.rotation}deg)`;

document.body.appendChild(htmlRect);

function drawPoint(point) {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.height = 10 + "px";
  el.style.width = 10 + "px";
  el.style.position = "absolute";
  el.style.background = "green";
  el.style.transformOrigin = "center center";
  el.style.transform = `translate3d(${point.x}px,${point.y}px,0)`;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}

var pointRotated = [];
pointRotated.push(
  getPointRotated(
    rect.x,
    rect.y,
    rect.rotation,
    -rect.width / 2,
    rect.height / 2
  )
);
pointRotated.push(
  getPointRotated(
    rect.x,
    rect.y,
    rect.rotation,
    rect.width / 2,
    rect.height / 2
  )
);
pointRotated.push(
  getPointRotated(
    rect.x,
    rect.y,
    rect.rotation,
    -rect.width / 2,
    -rect.height / 2
  )
);
pointRotated.push(
  getPointRotated(
    rect.x,
    rect.y,
    rect.rotation,
    rect.width / 2,
    -rect.height / 2
  )
);

for (let point of pointRotated) {
  drawPoint(point);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A rotation around the origin follows the equation

```
X = c x - s y
Y = s x + c y
```

where `c`, `s` are the cosine and sine of the angle.

A rotation around an arbitrary point `(u, v)` is

```
X = c (x - u) - s (y - v) + u
Y = s (x - u) + c (y - v) + v
```